# HQL does not ignore values with blank string in column

Tags: java, hql

I am trying to setup a query for my application to pull only values from a table that have a specific column set.  Mostly this column will be null, but if you edit and save the item on the application end without putting anything in this field, then it saves a blank string to that database field.

I have tried the TSQL query:

`SELECT * from TABLE where COLUMN is not NULL AND COLUMN != ''`

This query returns the results I need, but when I run the same query in HQL:

```
SELECT OBJECT from TABLE where COLUMN is not NULL and COLUMN <> ''
```

Then it still contains the values that have a blank string in that column.  I have tried this using HQL with the operators <> and !=, and have also tried converting it to a criteria object using `Restrictions.ne("column","")` but nothing seems to provide the result I need.

I tried Length as in the comments, but had no luck.  With the length in the query hibernate generates the full query as so.  the time_clock_id column is the one that i'm having the problem with.  Hibernate is set to SQLServerDialect

```
select timezone0_.time_zone_id as time1_368_, timezone0_.version as version368_, timezone0_.modification_timestamp as modifica3_368_, timezone0_.time_offset as time4_368_, timezone0_.modification_user as modifica5_368_, timezone0_.name as name368_, timezone0_.description as descript7_368_, timezone0_.active as active368_, timezone0_.time_clock_id as time9_368_ from time_zone timezone0_ where timezone0_.active=1 and (timezone0_.time_clock_id is not null) and len(timezone0_.time_clock_id)>0
```

Comment: Try using `LENGTH(COLUMN) > 0`.

Comment: what is hibernate generating?  Do you have the dialect set for your database?

Comment: Just tried Length and did not have any luck.  The Dialect set in the hibernate is SQLServerDialect

Comment: I updated the description to print out the full query that Hibernate generates.  I tried running this query in MSSQL and it did produce the results I am looking for, but the results in the application continue to differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rookie Mistake.  There was another place within my action class where I was using a different query to build the select list in the application.  This was resulting in the list being overwritten with all values instead of those that use blank.  After snipping this duplication I can use the operator `column <> ''` and I am getting the correct results